# Calculate the domain of Log function, which contains a Trigonometric fraction

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms

I'm trying to find the domain of the following function:

$$f(x)=log\Biggl(\frac{\displaystyle\tan(x) + 2|\sin(x)|}{\displaystyle 2\cos^2(2x) + 2\cos(2x)+5}\Biggr)$$

I have reasoned this way: since I have a logarithmic function, its argument must be posed $>0$; hence I "just" need to solve a Trigonometric fraction, which is:

$$\frac{\displaystyle\tan(x) + 2|\sin(x)|}{\displaystyle 2\cos^2(2x) + 2\cos(2x)+5}>0$$

For the *numerator*:

1. I multiply and divide it for $\cos(x)$, and now the solution must be different than $x=\frac π2+kπ, k\in N$;
2. I obtain: $\sin(x)[1+2\cos(x)]>0$;
3. Solution in $2π$ should be:  $0<x<\frac 23π \lor \frac 43π < x < 2π$;

For the *denominator* I couldn't find an algebric solution, I plotted the function and discovered that the denominator function is always bigger than zero.

Now, someone could say me if my calculus is wrong or could give me another way to determine the domain of $f(x)$? Thank you.

Comment: $$u=\cos{x}$$  solve for $$2u^2+2u+5=0$$

Comment: @rlartiga I tried, but the discriminating is less than zero.

Comment: Then the denominator is never zero, so what is your problem?

Comment: But I wanted to know if the denominator is bigger than zero or less than zero.

Comment: Ok, take $x=0$ then the denominator is bigger than zero, by continuity is always possitive.

Answer (score 1):

no HINT: $$2t^2+2t+5=2\left(t^2+t+\frac{5}{2}\right)=2\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{9}{2}>0$$

Comment: Thank you, I was able to demonstrate that the denominator is always positive. Anyway the correct way is: $2\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{9}{2}>0$